# using powershell .sql query output is saving column name in .txt or .sql file

Tags: powershell

Can anyone suggest me how to get rid of column names in the output file after executing the .sql file using powershell. I'm using the following method to achieve this

```
invoke-sqlcmd -inputfile C:\users\userbackup.sql -serverinstance DBATest -database Test | out-file C:\outputuser.sql
```

In the output file outputuser.sql ....i want to see only the rows without the column names.

Please help me on this.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread. Thought of sharing so that it helps others.

The below command works:

invoke-sqlcmd -inputfile C:\users\userbackup.sql -serverinstance DBATest -database Test | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders -Wrap| out-file C:\outputuser.sql

Comment: Thanks a lot Chad, its working like a charm. Now i'm only seeing the data in the output file. But in the output i'm missing some part of data.

Comment: Data should be like IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = 'Readonly')       CREATE USER [Readonly] FOR LOGIN [Readonly] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA =dbo;
IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = 'ReadWrite')       CREATE USER [ReadWrite] FOR LOGIN [ReadWrite] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA =dbo;
IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = 'domain\toe')  CREATE USER [domain\toe] FOR LOGIN [domain\toe]; but when the powershell generates output file i'm missing the create user part and it looks like this...

Comment: IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = 'Readonly')      ...
IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = 'ReadWrite')   ...
IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = 'domain\toe')   ... You can see the "..." instead of create user part. That means when the row is big enough it just generates ... instead of actual data. Please let me know how to fix this. Thanks in advance

Comment: I would play with the various parameters to format-table. The -wrap parameter looks promising.